# Dynamic control is not loading in phantomJs browser but its loading in IE,Firefox,Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, nightmare

I am trying to automate one scenario using phantomJS, in the scenario there is one dynamic grid. we have to populate the data in the grid manually. Before populating the grid one empty row should be displayed. That empty row is not being displayed in the phantomJS browser, while the row is being loaded in IE, Mozilla Firefox and google chrome. Below is the script I am using, and I have tried using all the ID's of the elements in the row and also tried to wait for it to load for enough time.

PhantomJS version - 2.1.1
Node JS version -0.12.13-x64.msi
python version  -3.5.1
Nightmare -1.8.2

```
.waitForVisible('#ID')  //this is one element in the row. but the row is not being displayed simply it is throwing errors.
.type('#ID', "AAA-2121")
.pressTab('#ID')
.screenshot(resultfolder + '/06.sku-Details.png')
.pressTab('#ID')
.wait(3000)
```

Comment: What's the module that you're using? Is it nightmare?

Comment: If you are using Nightmare, which version?